# Replacing values in a data.frame that have lost their order

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

In my toy `data`, for each unique `study`, the **numeric** variables (`sample` and `group`) must have an order starting from `1`. But:

For example, in `study 1`, we see that there are two unique `sample` values (`1` & `3`), so `3` must be replaced with `2`.

For example, in `study 2`, we see that there  is one unique `group` value (`2`), so it must be replaced with `1`.

In `study 3`, both `sample` and `group` seem ok meaning their unique values are `1` and `2` (no replacing needed).

For this toy `data`, my ***desired output*** is shown below. But I appreciate a functional solution that can automatically replace any number of **numeric** variables in a data.frame that have lost their order just like I showed in my toy `data`.

```
m="
study sample group outcome
1      1     1       A
1      1     1       B
1      1     2       A
1      1     2       B 
1      3     1       A
1      3     1       B
1      3     2       A
1      3     2       B

2      1     2       A
2      1     2       B
2      2     2       A
2      2     2       B
2      3     2       A
2      3     2       B

3      1     1       A
3      1     1       B
3      1     2       A
3      1     2       B
3      2     1       A
3      2     1       B
3      2     2       A
3      2     2       B"

data <- read.table(text=m, h=T)

Desired_output="
study sample group outcome
1      1     1       A
1      1     1       B
1      1     2       A
1      1     2       B 
1      2     1       A
1      2     1       B
1      2     2       A
1      2     2       B

2      1     1       A
2      1     1       B
2      2     1       A
2      2     1       B
2      3     1       A
2      3     1       B

3      1     1       A
3      1     1       B
3      1     2       A
3      1     2       B
3      2     1       A
3      2     1       B
3      2     2       A
3      2     2       B"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(study) %>% 
  mutate(across(tidyselect::vars_select_helpers$where(is.numeric),
                function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

The resultant data frame looks like this:

```r
   study sample group outcome
1      1      1     1       A
2      1      1     1       B
3      1      1     2       A
4      1      1     2       B
5      1      2     1       A
6      1      2     1       B
7      1      2     2       A
8      1      2     2       B
9      2      1     1       A
10     2      1     1       B
11     2      2     1       A
12     2      2     1       B
13     2      3     1       A
14     2      3     1       B
15     3      1     1       A
16     3      1     1       B
17     3      1     2       A
18     3      1     2       B
19     3      2     1       A
20     3      2     1       B
21     3      2     2       A
22     3      2     2       B
```

Comment: @SimonHarmel see my update - this should now work for all numeric columns in your data frame at the same time

Comment: both accept and +1. But I may need to check this more thoroughly.

Comment: Allan, if I want to leave one or more numeric variables from your function untouched while they still should be part of the output, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @SimonHarmel the first argument to `across` allows you to specify the columns to which the transformation is applied. In my example, we are selecting according to whether the columns are numeric. However, you could manually select the columns by supplying their names, such as `mutate(across(all_of(c("sample", "group")), function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x))))` . There are several ways to select the columns you want - see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative (not as elegant as @Allan Cameron +1 ) `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(study) %>% 
  mutate(x = n()/length(unique(sample)),
         sample =  rep(row_number(), each=x, length.out = n()),
         y = length(unique(group)),
         group = ifelse(y==1, 1, group)) %>% 
  select(-x, -y)
```

```
   study sample group outcome
   <int>  <int> <dbl> <chr>  
 1     1      1     1 A      
 2     1      1     1 B      
 3     1      1     2 A      
 4     1      1     2 B      
 5     1      2     1 A      
 6     1      2     1 B      
 7     1      2     2 A      
 8     1      2     2 B      
 9     2      1     1 A      
10     2      1     1 B      
11     2      2     1 A      
12     2      2     1 B      
13     2      3     1 A      
14     2      3     1 B      
15     3      1     1 A      
16     3      1     1 B      
17     3      1     2 A      
18     3      1     2 B      
19     3      2     1 A      
20     3      2     1 B      
21     3      2     2 A      
22     3      2     2 B
```